Work in Python with large date years without limitations of DateTime, epoch
I searched a lot about this issue and surprisingly I didn't find anything useful.
I made a program in Python inspired in relativity theory. A dilation time is calculated in seconds and then sums it to the time in the time dilation zone to see which year is in the Earth when ship comes back.
If code needed I can add it, just ask for it, but I think it's not necessary to answer my question.
Ok until here, the problem resides in "epoch", "datetime", etc. because the limit on 9999 year (or 2038 with epoch 32bit). I want to made a joke with year 802702 and the Morlocks, and for now I can only return date in format string, not date. Any idea of how can I return that kind of years in date format?
Summary: I want to work and return with dates (date format) with years greater than 9999 and more than 4 digits.

Going beyond a couple of thousand years into the future, there’s probably no point in second, day or even year accuracy, is there? Just calculate years using ints or floats? Whether you skip leap years or are off by floating point accuracy probably doesn’t matter for talking about the year 802702, does it?

Only accuracy with year in this case 'cause the H. G. Welles reference, nothing else. But epoch works in seconds; since 01/01/1970 the number is incrementing realtime so long digit of seconds is a date accured with seconds and its limit is year 2038 'cause its 32bits and with DateTime limit is 9999 (4 digit years). So the problem aren't unities nor leap years to obtain a date type variable with big year but the limited libraries, at least in Python.

Again, I don’t know what kind of math you’re trying to do, but if you just need year accuracy, just use an int to represent a year. If you need it a little more fine grained, use an int for representing days and divide by 365 to get years. That’ll be close enough for most purposes, unless you can clarify more why it’s not.

I don't need accuracy, but I need to work in seconds. So I guess as you say I can parse it into years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds and convert into a date with a custom class as asur suggested too, so it's the only way in Python to handle years of more than 4 digit. I don't know if I missunderstood (again), sorry.

You can use floats or ints to calculate in seconds even. Python ints are unlimited, and floats just lose accuracy, which is immaterial. You just need to do the rough conversion from seconds to years with simple math instead of using datetime libraries.

And here is where the complication arrives. When I have the years, months, days... How I parse it into a Date variable type if that libraries are so limited in Python? It's what I'm not understanding completely. I am forced to return as string? Sorry for repeating the so basic questions, but I am not getting it...

I think the idea you're missing is: forgo any date/time types. Don't use any "Date variable type". Just use ints. time.time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 800000) to get an (approximate) epoch timestamp 800k years in the future. A little more math and dividing by 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 to turn that into years.

Hi. The epoch stamp is one of the requieriments, yes, but other one is the date in format after time dilation as I said before. I answered to the next answer the reaso guess I'll have to handle dates as strings. Sorry that I didn't specified the reason of why has to be a date in format in the topic. Anyway the info you shared is very useful. Thanks so much.

To handle dates beyond the typical range supported by Python;s built-in datetime module(which is limited to years 1 through 9999),you can use the datetime library's datetime class for calculations,but for years beyond that, you might consider using custom classes or libraries that can handle arbitrary ranges.
Custom Date Class :
To handle dates with random years, your could write own class.
Here is a basic example:
enter image description here

Thanks so much, this is what I was looking for.

Don't post links to images of text, put the text in the answer.

For dates 800k years in the future, second, day or even month accuracy surely is superfluous. Meaning, you don't need to accurately take into account leap seconds, timezones or any of that. You just need a rough estimation of the year, which you can do with simple math without any limited date libraries whatsoever:
>>> import time

>>> seconds_in_a_year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
>>> timestamp_now = time.time()
>>> future_timestamp = timestamp_now + (800_000 * seconds_in_a_year)
>>> future_year = int(future_timestamp / seconds_in_a_year) + 1970

>>> future_timestamp
25230529088174.812

>>> future_year
802024

That's all you need to calculate an approximate Epoch timestamp 800k years in the future, and to turn it into the year. The + 1970 is because Epoch timestamps start January 1st 1970.

Hi. Thanks for the answer. I initially asked for a Date type to learn if there was a library or something that could handle it and to make the exercise a bit more challenging (I didn't specify this is an exercise I'm designing for others to practice in CodeWars, sorry).
In the end, a string with data resultson it has to be returned, and one of this data element is the final date after time dilation. Thanks a lot for the code, information, and explanation though, it’s very useful. The year itself (around 80200) is just a reference to the Morlocks from H. G. Wells' "The Time Machine".
